# Add a bounty for a community wiki question?

Tags: support, bounty, community-wiki

So say there's a community wiki question, not my own, that I think deserves more attention. Can I put a bounty on it?

**[The FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq)** says:

> As an additional bonus, bounty awards
>   are immune to the daily reputation cap
>   and community wiki mode.

I take that to mean I should be able to add a bounty in that instance. Is that true or am I misreading the intent of that sentence in the faq. If I've misread it, perhaps it needs a rephrase for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can -- bounty ignores community wiki status and behaves as if the question is a "normal" question.

Comment: Okay, I think it must be that I already have a question I attached a bounty to, so I can't have more than one at a time. I'll look again once my existing bounty has run its course.

Comment: Indeed, now that my prior bounty closed, I was able to attach a bounty to someone else's community wiki question.